# Spring mvc checkbox selected value not readable as a string (values are in korean language)

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jsp, checkbox, cjk

I'm working with Spring MVC develping REST API. I have checkboxes that are created automatically. The value of a check box is displayed on the web page in Korean, when I select one checkbox, it returns an unreadable string. I have added `<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>` tag in my jsp page and annotation my function in controlar like this `RequestMapping(value = "/filterSubmit", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/json;charset=UTF-8" )` also I have added `URIEncoding="UTF-8"` to tomcat server.xml `<Connector  URIEncoding="UTF-8" connectionTimeout="20000" port="8081" protocol="HTTP/1.1" redirectPort="8443"/>` still, I cannot read the selected value?

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know, CJK (Chinese/Korean/Japanese) doesn't use UTF-8 encoding. So maybe your problem is encoding. Try some other pageEncoding

References: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Korean_language_and_computers